# PHP $_SESSION stops execution

Tags: php, macos, apache, session

I was trying to get my OS X localhost PHP scripts to send mail, so I followed [this tutorial](http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/12/03/setup-a-testing-mail-server-using-php-on-mac-os-x/). I was able to get `mail( )` to send after completing the article, but now something is wrong with sessions.

I have a page that used to work with the following:

```
<!-- ... -->
<?php include( 'search-form.php' ); ?>
<?php include( 'site-navigation.php' ); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, the page rendering stops at the `site-navigation.php` include.  I was able to locate exactly what line stops execution and it is the if-statement below:

**site-navigation.php :**

```
        <section>
            <h2>Site Navigation</h2>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                    </li>
<?php
if( isset( $_SESSION['uid'] ) ) :
?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="view-user.php?uid=<?= $_SESSION['uid']; ?>">User Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                    </li>
<?
endif;
?>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
```

Commenting that out allows execution to proceed, but what could I have done to cause it to stop working as it did before? I really don't want to do a full reinstall, but if I have to, so be it.

My only guess is that when I copied `php.ini.default` to `php.ini` it overwrote some settings that I didn't know I had. What could those settings be?

Comment: is `isset( $_SESSION ) === true`?

Comment: `var_dump(isset($_SESSION))` outputs `bool(true)`. In this case, `$_SESSION` is an empty array, which is expected.

Comment: [`if(something):` needs an `endif;`...](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: @Wrikken, It does. My mistake for not including that.

Comment: OK, if that's ok. moving on: Does it stop with a fatal error, or just 'hangs' there (you _do_ have full error reporting enabled & you show those errors on development)? Cause in the latter case. I can imagine some process hangs hogging the session id (in which case, you might want to call `session_write_close()` before your freshly added `mail()` call, or whatever possibly long-running-code you have.

Comment: @Wrikken, thanks. I was able to get it to render a Parse error on `site-navigation.php` at line 24. line 24 is a blank line, but I'm going to put the full source in my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem is.  It appears that short-tags are not working.

Changing:

```
<?
endif;
?>
```

To:

```
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Allows execution to proceed.  Now, I just need to figure out how to get short-tags working again.  Or, better yet, fix my code so it doesn't have these unnoticed anomalies.

Thanks @Wrikken for helping me figure it out.

Comment: It is recommended that you leave short tags off. They conflict with XML syntax and are dropped in later versions of PHP.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as such. I wondered how my configuration was to have short tags enabled, but I suppose it is a good thing this happened in order to improve the two occurrences that I had not noticed I was using them.